# Sails.js Migrate - Alter (Not Updating the table columns)

Tags: node.js, sails.js, migrate, alter

As the per the definition of `migrate:'alter'`, It should add/remove columns in the DB on lifting the sails application. But I see it's not doing it .. I'm lifting the sails after adding new fields and removing existing fields in a model to see the changes with `migrate:'alter'`, but I couldn't see the changes.. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which connection are you using? And how do you confirm that its not working? Is  it crashing. You can check it from blueprint apis.

Comment: I'm using MongoDB and 'sails-mongo' adapter.. It's not crashing... Just to give an overview of what I'm doing/testing... I've loaded few records in the 'User' collection, then have added **new fields (required with default value)** and **removed** some existing fields and I'm expecting sails to **add/remove** those fields on lifting the application.. And I didn't see any change.. Just wanted to know what exactly **migrate:alter** will do and need to test the same

Answer (score 0):

as in [sails model docs](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings) alter migration will auto-migrate columns/fields, but attempt to keep my existing data (experimental)

so if you remove some columns or add a validation it won't be applied [I'm using sails-mongo adapter] unless
you use 'safe' and edit the database by yourself or 'drop' which will drop
all the tables and rebuild correct ones